# Magento2 Creating a new directory

Tags: magento2, php, core-file-storage

I am trying to create a new directory in /pub/media/import folder. Creating a directory works with `mkdir()` but I'm having issues with folder persmission rights.

How would I create a directory with `Magento\Framework\Filesystem`?

My current code:

```
private function createImagesDir()
{
    if ( ! file_exists($this->directoryList->getPath('media').'/import/images')) {
        mkdir($this->directoryList->getPath('media').'/import/images','775', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File`.
Either inject an instance of it in your class or instantiate it manually using `new`.
Then do this:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io **/
$io->mkdir($this->directoryList->getPath('media').'/import/images', 0775);
```

Also, the problem might be because your rights say `'775'` as string. Try changing it to `0775`.

Answer (score 3):

Check Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File , there already is a specific method checkAndCreateFolder .

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes less is more.

The simplest option is to not specify the file permissions.

Leave it to the webserver to create a folder it can read using the default umask.

For example:

```
private $file;
private $dir;



public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $file,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    ...
) {
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->dir = $dir;
    ...
}



private function getImageImportFolder()
{
    $images = $this->dir->getPath('media').'/import/images';
    if ( ! file_exists($images)) {
        $this->file->mkdir($images);
    }
    return $images . '/';
}
```