# Create a folder in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.2, php-7

I have created a folder in pub/media by refer this link

> [Magento2 Creating a new directory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119747/magento2-creating-a-new-directory)

But i can't insert any images in this folder

How to insert the images in specific folder

Thanks

Comment: How do you try to insert images into that folder?

Comment: i want to create a folder for resizing the image